# MatAutocomplete value X display

Tags: angular, angular-material

My Autocomplete shows the values from an object with this definition:

```
export class Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  cityName: string;
}
```

This is the autocomplete template:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Person" aria-label="Person" matInput formControlName="personId" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions" [value]="item">
        {{ item.name }}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

And this is the displayWith function:

```
displayFn(value?: any) {
  return value ? value.name : undefined;
}
```

It works, but the formControl binded to this autocomplete receives the entire item object:

```
 {
    id: 1;
    name: "John";
    cityName: "Dallas";
 }
```

How can I get only the "id" value in the formControl ?

Comment: As a side note you do not need `.bind(this)` on the `<mat-autocomplete` line of code. That function does not use `this`.

Comment: @Igor, ok. I was using in the official code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to do 2 things.

1. Update the template so that the `[value]` bounds to `id` instead of the object.
2. Update the `displayFn` so that the passed in `id` is used to lookup the object and return the name which will then be displayed in the input.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Person" aria-label="Person" matInput formControlName="personId" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions" [value]="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
displayFn(value?: number) {
  return value ? this.filteredOptions.find(_ => _.id === value).name : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FormControl` receives the entire item because you are binding the `[value]` property of each `<mat-option>` to the entire item.

To have it so only the `id` is passed to the `FormControl` replace:

`<mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions" [value]="item">`

with

`<mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions" [value]="item.id">`

As Igor said, you will then need to update your `displayFn` function to display the name of the `Person`.

Comment: Don't works. Doing this, it display the "id" in the input element after I choose an item.